Flink Buffer pool has already been destroyed
I have a Flink Job, It has been running normally for half a month, But since the last run failed, now every time I restart and run for half an hour, it still fails.
I deleted the operator at the end of the output to HDFS and it ran normally.
I suspect: 1. Data issues 2. Operator issues 3. HDFS issues
but:
1. Knowing that the checkpoint was always normal before the failure, so it is not a data issue;
2. If there is a problem with the operator, it will explode in the first half month and run normally after startup;
3. HDFS can be written normally and there are no HDFS error messages (HDFS server logs cannot be viewed temporarily)
This is an error message：
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(BroadcastingOutputCollector.java:84) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator$ContextImpl.output(ProcessOperator.java:103) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.function.FilterProcessFunction2.processElement(FilterProcessFunction2.java:263) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.function.FilterProcessFunction2.processElement(FilterProcessFunction2.java:43) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.parent.global.PaStreamBatchFlatMap.doBatch(PaStreamBatchFlatMap.java:290) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.parent.global.PaStreamBatchFlatMap.processElement(PaStreamBatchFlatMap.java:219) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator$ContextImpl.output(ProcessOperator.java:103) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.function.FilterProcessFunction2.processElement(FilterProcessFunction2.java:263) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.function.FilterProcessFunction2.processElement(FilterProcessFunction2.java:43) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:423) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:528) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$SwitchingOnClose.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:108) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordsWithTimestamps(AbstractFetcher.java:376) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:183) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:142) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:859) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.component.flink.kafka.KafkaSourceComponent.run(KafkaSourceComponent.java:189) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:67) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:333) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.completionBaseTuple(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:195) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:159) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.CancelTaskException: Buffer pool has already been destroyed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.checkDestroyed(LocalBufferPool.java:422) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestMemorySegment(LocalBufferPool.java:397) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.LocalBufferPool.requestBufferBuilder(LocalBufferPool.java:340) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.requestNewBufferBuilderFromPool(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:407) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.requestNewUnicastBufferBuilder(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:390) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.appendUnicastDataForNewRecord(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:294) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.emitRecord(BufferWritingResultPartition.java:156) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:107) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.ChannelSelectorRecordWriter.emit(ChannelSelectorRecordWriter.java:54) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:105) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:91) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:45) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.completionBaseTuple(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:195) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:159) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    ... 63 more

and：
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:62) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator$ContextImpl.output(ProcessOperator.java:103) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.function.FilterProcessFunction2.processElement(FilterProcessFunction2.java:263) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.function.FilterProcessFunction2.processElement(FilterProcessFunction2.java:43) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$ManualWatermarkContext.processAndCollectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:423) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$WatermarkContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:528) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$SwitchingOnClose.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:108) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordsWithTimestamps(AbstractFetcher.java:376) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:183) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:142) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:859) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.component.flink.kafka.KafkaSourceComponent.run(KafkaSourceComponent.java:189) ~[843345264_3212326681260319440lib_pipeace-component-source-flink-kafka-294-jar-with-dependencies.jar:2.9.4]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:67) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:333) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:99) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.parent.global.PaStreamBatchFlatMap.doBatch(PaStreamBatchFlatMap.java:290) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.parent.global.PaStreamBatchFlatMap.processElement(PaStreamBatchFlatMap.java:219) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:57) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:56) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.CountingOutput.collect(CountingOutput.java:29) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.collector.PaProcessCollectorNormal.collect(PaProcessCollectorNormal.java:20) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at cn.com.bsfit.pipeace.apis.component.process.PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.processElement(PaProcessorFlatMapFunction.java:166) ~[1436212209_7852397891832665347lib_pipeace-apis-2.9.4-yszf-3.jar:2.9.4-yszf-3]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(CopyingChainingOutput.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Strangely, the reason for the error is that it calls the collect method to output data downstream, and the error is reported by other operators above it instead of the HDFS operator (and the error operator is different each time), and the HDFS operator also calls the close method, causing the client to close and the checkpoint to fail
taskmanager.memory.network.fraction 0.2.But it doesn't work

Given the presence of cn.com.bsfit.pipeace in the stack trace, it looks like perhaps you are using another framework together with Flink? I also wonder which sink you are using to write to HDFS, and what versions of Flink and the other components are being used. I don't think we have enough information to reproduce or debug this problem.
